# What if my seasonal decompose is completely coloured?

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, prediction, seasonality

I have a dataset for solar output, at day the values are positive but at night the values are 0. When i try the seasonal_decompose() function It gives me the following result:

[image]

Im pretty sure the difference between day and night is a seasonality (right?).

This is my code:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(df1, model='additive',freq=96)
result.plot()
plt.show()
```

freq = 96 because my data is per 15 minutes.

What does this graphs tell me?

Comment: What solar output variable did you measure? Units of measurement?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I measured the Solar output in MW

Comment: And why does it have such an increasing (modulo sesonality) trend over time? Something with the measurement conditions? It looks suspicious!

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar graph as yours for a seasonal sale data and after I increased my freq variable to 365 I got the seasonal pattern, before it was all colored. It could be something similar for you. Your freq is not suitable for your data.

Answer (score 1):

The plot from your question shows "overplotting": to many dots or lines in small graph and one cannot see too much.

You can zoom in to see details, i.e., reduce the time span, say pick only 3 month to plot.

In addition, the `freq` setting may be wrong, data is per 15 min does not mean the freq is 96 because "solar data" may not have freq of 1 day.